# How to install iOS 9.x Simulator on Xcode 11?

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm developing and iOS app with **iOS 9** support, but with **Xcode 11** update I'm missing the possibility to add / install **iOS 9 simulator**.
Is there any chance to have **iOS 9.x simulator in Xcode 11**?

[image: Xcode 11 "Components"]

Comment: Which macOS version you have? I seem to have lost iOS 9 simulator after upgrade to 10.15 Catalina.

Comment: I have Mojave (10.14.6), but the 9.x simulators are not present :(

Comment: Same here, with 10.14.6 I lost 9.x simulators and none of the solutions provided here work.

Comment: It is not working now....@JamesP After following every step it does load the simulator but with the minimum iOS version supported by Xcode 11.3 (iOS version - 10.3.1)

Answer (score 20):

It seems iOS 9 simulator is supported by Xcode 11, but only on macOS 10.14 Mojave. After upgrade to macOS 10.15 Catalina, this simulator is not supported any more.

Though I didn't find confirmation of this in any release notes. The only acknowledgment I found is this tweet by Apple engineer: https://twitter.com/xenadu02/status/1140093901438689280?lang=en

Comment: I have Mojave (10.14.6) but the 9.x simulators are not present

Comment: @Levi If you have Mojave, try to download iOS 9 simulator file with any download manager software and then install the simulator  

9.3: https://devimages-cdn.apple.com/downloads/xcode/simulators/com.apple.pkg.iPhoneSimulatorSDK9_3-9.3.1.1460411551.dmg

9.0: https://devimages-cdn.apple.com/downloads/xcode/simulators/com.apple.pkg.iPhoneSimulatorSDK9_0-9.0.1.1443554484.dmg

Comment: Thanks. I was looking for these exact links to the simulator dmg files. Guys, you can use iGetter fast downloader: https://www.igetter.net/downloads.html. And to install the downloaded files visit this article: https://hackernoon.com/manually-install-ios-simulators-in-xcode-f7e4bbe50753

Comment: Hasaan, that article is helpful, but after following the steps, my XCode 11.3.1 on Mojave 10.14.5 still doesn't show any iOS simulator version before 10.3.1.

Comment: Apple makes trouble for developer.

Answer (score 2):

I tried installing Xcode 10.1 on my Mac, but it also did not work for iOS9, i suspect it has to do with Apple dropping support for 32 bit applications (like iOS9)

Answer (score 2):

iOS 9.3 (9.3 - 13E233) - com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-9-3 (unavailable, The iOS 9.3 simulator runtime is not supported on hosts after macOS 10.14.99.) (unavailable, The iOS 9.3 simulator runtime is not supported on hosts after macOS 10.14.99.)

Comment: looks like a warn or error can you also explain your answer to make it more acceptable

Answer (score 2):

I've got **macOS Catalina 10.15.5** currently installed and the only solution I found to test my app on iOS 9 simulator it's described in the following steps:

1. create a virtual machine with **macOS Mojave 10.14.4** (following steps are done into the virtual machine)
2. install **Xcode 10.2.1**
3. Download and install the simulators you need from **Preferences/Components**
4. install **Xcode 11**

Now you should be able to test your app on iOS 9... kind of

Answer (score -3):

iOS 9.0 is not supported by Xcode 11.

Answer (score -3):

Jayaraj M, it's not a true:

> Xcode 11 is available in the Mac App Store and includes SDKs for iOS
>   13, macOS Catalina 10.15, watchOS 6, and tvOS 13. Xcode 11 supports
>   development for devices running iOS 13.1. Xcode 11 supports on-device
>   debugging for iOS 8 and later, tvOS 9 and later, and watchOS 2 and
>   later. Xcode 11 requires a Mac running macOS Mojave 10.14.4 or later.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode_release_notes/xcode_11_release_notes

Comment: The important thing to note in Apple's note above is "on-device debugging". If you have a device with the older iOS, you can still debug it. But the simulators for iOS9  are gone. Tried to see if I could build an iOS 9 simulator (was successful building iOS 11 simulator that I needed). But following fails: xcrun simctl create "iPhone 5" "com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-5" "com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-9-0"